# xmlhttp not responding JS to Node

Tags: javascript, node.js, xmlhttprequest

I've got a request from an html page to a Node service.

The service works perfectly in Firefox and Chrome when accessed through url. Works perfectly when I use curl and also with Postman.

When I use XMLhttpsRequest it launches the onerror associated function and end up with *readyState* 4, *status* 0.

I don't know why, at a given time Firefox let me know through the developer's console that I was cross accessing (Tho I am accessing localhost, but I won't loose it for it) (By the way: I never received the "crossing" message again I surely touch a sensible key with my console.logs that I should have erased)

So I incorporated this midleware to my server:

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
   res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
   res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");

   next();
});
```

When I run it in Chrome it says:
*GET https://localhost:3000/oficina/9999 net::ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED*
I swear that's not true.

My Ajax code is this:

```
function accede(accion,url,fn) {
    var xobj = new XMLHttpRequest();

//            console.log("accion: ", accion);
//            console.log("url   : ", url);

    xobj.overrideMimeType("application/json");
    xobj.open(accion, url, true);
    xobj.onerror = (e) => { 
        alert("Error del Navegador!!!\nStatus: " +xobj.status +" (" +xobj.statusText+")") 
        console.log("Falló, Header:")
        console.log(xobj.headers)
    }
    xobj.onprogress = (e) => {
        console.log("Progress: ")
    }
    xobj.onreadystatechange = () => {
        console.log("State:",xobj.readyState,"Status:", xobj.status)
        if (xobj.readyState == 4 && xobj.status == "200") {
            console.log("Fifó!")
        }
    };
    xobj.onload = () => { fn(JSON.parse(xobj.responseText)) };
    xobj.send();
}
```

The whole code is in:
https://github.com/elmasbestia/bnsvr

May somebody help me?

Comment: Use fetch(): https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch : it will greatly simplify your code.

Comment: Looked at your project - it is very incomplete. None of your dependencies are listed in the project.json file and the Bienes JSON file doesn't exist. It is very difficult to help without knowing the whole picture.  But since you say it is flawless with the exception of this code, then I suppose we ignore that.  **Please provide the content of the browser address bar when this issue occurs.**

Answer (score 0):

why don't you get the javascript code from postman
[image]

I tried 2 methods . from chrome and form console. both work
I get 500's due to exception on the server though

[image]

also, why are you using https? i don't see your express server being https

Comment: It's very useful tool, nonetheless, I copied it, paste it in my code and it didn't worked out either.